# Разрешить индексацию тега - index

Tags: seo, индексация, поисковые-системы

Есть тег `noindex`, который запрещает индексацию определенного текста. Существует ли обратный тег? Т.е. чтоб было запрещено индексировать все, кроме определенного параграфа?

Что-то вроде этого:

```
<index>этот текст разрешен для индексации</index>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Существует ли обратный тег?

Нет.